# How to Dynamically add Direcitves angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have successfully Added an angularjs directive into another directive using this code

```
var newElement = $compile( "<div my-diretive='n'></div>" )( $scope );
$element.parent().append( newElement );
```

but how can i pass the `my-diretive='n'` n value dynamically .

```
$scope.showDirective = function(item){

    var newElement = $compile( "<div my-diretive='n'></div>" )( $scope ); 
    //here i want to replace 'n' with item

    $element.parent().append( newElement );


   }
```

is it possible to pass the value or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myDirective` has isolated scope, this will create two-way data binding:

```
$scope.showDirective = function(item){

    $scope.item = item;
    // the interpolation will be against $scope with item available on it
    var newElement = $compile( "<div my-diretive='item'></div>" )( $scope ); 
    $element.parent().append( newElement );
}
```

Let us know, if it works for you.